# Why is my radio button not detected as checked?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I hate when I am spending so much time on basic questions like this that seems so easy in my head but just don't work.

I have a page with two radio button and regarding which one I click it should send me to a related page.

The DOM :

```
<form id="question-form4" class="list">
      <ion-radio id="question-checkbox1">YES</ion-radio>
      <ion-radio id="question-checkbox2">NO</ion-radio>
    </form>
    <button ng-click="next()" type="submit" class="button button-assertive  button-block">NEXT</button>
```

The controller :

```
$scope.next = function(){

  if(document.getElementById('question-checkbox1').checked = true ) {
  //Male radio button is checked
  $state.go('photo');
}else if(document.getElementById('question-checkbox2').checked = true) {
  //Female radio button is checked
  $state.go('prescription');
}
}
```

And of course, whatever I choose, it always send me to the page "photo". What can I possibly do wrong ?

Comment: Is it a `=` vs `==` issue?

Comment: `document.getElementById('question-checkbox1').checked = true` will eval to true every single time. (Because of what @ÁlvaroGonzález said)

Comment: Hello, it doesn't trigger anything to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your conditions with following. As @Alvirp said, it's `=` vs `==` issue.

```
 if(document.getElementById('question-checkbox1').checked == true )
```

and

```
else if(document.getElementById('question-checkbox2').checked == true)
```

Comment: Hello, it doesn't trigger anything to do so.

Comment: Technically you don't even need the `== true` because `checked` is already a boolean

Comment: After adding `==`, do you still go to "photo"?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, after all solutions given being the same and not working, I found a "method" that is more complicated, not making any real sens to me but that works :

1 ) Adding `ng-model` in the two radio buttons :

```
<ion-radio ng-model="value.name" value="yes" id="question-checkbox1">YES</ion-radio>
      <ion-radio ng-model="value.name" value="no" id="question-checkbox2">NO</ion-radio>
```

2 ) Adding an external `<p>` with the value of the `ng-model` :

```
<p id="final">{{value.name}}</p>
```

3 ) Comparing in the controller the value of the `<p>` :

```
$scope.next = function(){

   if(document.getElementById('final').textContent == "yes" ) {
  //Male radio button is checked
  $state.go('photo');
}else if(document.getElementById('final').textContent == "no") {
  //Female radio button is checked
  $state.go('prescription');
}
}
```

This took me one hour and a half. Hope it helps somebody.